# Good default tomcat server.xml for AWS ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: performance, configuration, tomcat7, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My setup is a WAR deployed though elasticBeanstalk on a Tomcat7/Java7 app. I'm doing basic HTML with Servlets, and REST. Nothing fancy.

I would like to replace the default server.xml for Tomcat7/Java7 under my elasticBeanstalk. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html

I'm a bit confused.

1. I'm looking for reasonable performance tuning numbers for the parameters there.
2. Looking for good defaults for security as well
3. Should I touch the AJP connector? (every request goes to a servlet) what should I configure?
4. Does this setup have Apache as a front-end, or do the HTTP requests go directly to Tomcat?

My instance is choking after a relatively low amount of concurrent users, with ~9% CPU, and plenty of DB connections. Am I jumping to conclusions with server.xml?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. AJP is not necessary as you have mentioned that most of the URL requests are servlet based. You can use AJP incase if you have more static contents to serve.
2. Most of the cases the performance tuning needs to be done at the web frontend part. Below are my suggestions.
3. Use gzip compression for web contents.
4. Make your pages cachable by using cache related HTTP headers (Etag, Expires, Cache-control,). By doing so you will reduce the number of unwanted HTTP requests.
5. JS and CSS can be [minified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29) inorder to reduce their sizes.
6. Check if you are getting more traffic from web crawlers. If you are getting more traffic from those try to reuse web sessions with [Crawler_Session_Manager_Valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Crawler_Session_Manager_Valve).
7. Try to index key tables of your database.
8. Make sure you are using DB connection pooling instead of opening new connections for every new request.
9. Avoid unwanted URL redirections (302, 304).

Incase if you are looking for a good book that can help you optimize your website refer [High Performance Web Sites for O'Reilly](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529307.do)

Comment: Hi & Thanks! 2. Do you know if a aws beanStalk Tomcat/Java setup has a web server, or just tomcat?  9. I use 304 for requests who's content has not changed. Is that bad?

Comment: 2) I am no idea about beanStalk mostly they should not have a separate web server. 9) Using 304 for contents that are not changed is the proper way to use.